# OpenCV VideoCapture Not Opening

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to use OpenCV's cv2 python bindings on an Amazon server running Ubuntu 14.04 and I can't seem to get VideoCapture to work properly.

I tried opening the default capture as follows:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.isOpened() #Returns false
```

I tested this on my local machine and it was true as expected, so there is something wrong with my open CV configuration. I've tried a variety of things:

- Using an actual filepath that I confirmed points to an .mp4 file
- Using -1 and 1 in place of 0 on the second line
- Installing ffmpeg (from a ppa as it isn't available by default on Ubuntu 14.04) and rebuilding OpenCV
- Removing my OpenCV directory entirely and rebuilding using the script [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV)
- Verifying and reinstalling various other libraries including x264, gstreamer, and gtk

I'm kind of out of ideas at this point. Any ideas of what could be going wrong?

Edit: OpenCV version is 2.4.9.

Comment: As I know `VideoCapture` is for capturing video from camera but Amazon servers have not camera.

Comment: VideoCapture is also used to capture video from files, which is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: As I see in documentations `VideoCapture(0)` means `use default camera`. Probabably need more code to do this.

Comment: Yes, after reading your comment I considered that, perhaps it only works locally because I have a camera on my local machine. However, switching `VideoCapture(0)` with `VideoCapture("/path/to/video/video.mp4")` returns the same error.

Comment: Well, first I would check path to video file on server, second I would download video file from server to local computer and check if I can still open it - maybe there was some problem with sending video file on server.

Comment: Thanks - it actually just started working. I'm not entirely sure why, but the most recent thing I did was reinstall ffmpeg via instructions here: http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

Comment: hi, did you able to capture video from camera in anyway??

Answer (score 9):

I also faced a similar problem. Possible solutions:

1. Check if you have given the correct path.
2. If you have installed OpenCV using pip, it will not work. You can remove OpenCV and reinstall it looking at the [official documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html).
3. Ways to install via pip, 
   `pip install opencv-python`         Only installs main module
   `pip install opencv-contrib-python` Install main and contrib module, so use this command.

Comment: `pip install opencv-contrib-python` solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and was solved successfully.
You should to build OpenCV with WITH_FFMPEG flag:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DWITH_GTK=ON -DWITH_FFMPEG=1
```

And you should view "YES" everywhere in section FFMPEG:

```
Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.2.5)
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       avcodec:                   YES (ver 57.107.100)
--       avformat:                  YES (ver 57.83.100)
--       avutil:                    YES (ver 55.78.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 4.8.100)
--       avresample:                YES (ver 3.7.0)
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    NO/YES
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        NO
```

If you will not see it then need to install next packages via apt (if you are using Debian or Ubuntu Linux):

```
sudo apt-get install libav-tools libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavutil-dev libswscale-dev libx264-dev
```